# What is a good way to handle slf4j logging in a web app deployed in Glassfish 3.0.1?

Tags: java, logging, glassfish, glassfish-3, slf4j

I have a quite ordinary web application which logs with slf4j, which is fine, and I have used several slf4j backends without any problems.

Under Tomcat I just told logback to point at a location in the filesystem and log there, but now I want to deploy several independent instances of this application each in its own domain in a single Glassfish 3.0.1 instance, and I have now found that I would like my slf4j logging to work well with Glassfish.

What would be a good way (dare I say "best") to have my logging taken care of by Glassfish.  Should I just flatten my logs to System.out with logback and let Glassfish handle the console output, or is there a better, standard way to reach the loggers inside Glassfish?

---

EDIT:  Investigation has shown that GlassFish 3.0.1 does not provide neither the SLF4J API or a binding in the classes visible to a JSP-page with default configuration.

By providing slf4j-api-X.jar and slf4j-jdk14-X.jar the slf4j-logging events are forwarded to java.util.logging which is captured properly by Glassfish (see http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7692/abluj?l=en&a=view for details).

Comment: Can you enter your findings as an answer? Then the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigation has shown that GlassFish 3.0.1 does not provide neither the SLF4J API or a binding in the classes visible to a JSP-page with default configuration.

By providing slf4j-api-X.jar and slf4j-jdk14-X.jar the slf4j-logging events are forwarded to java.util.logging which is captured properly by Glassfish (see http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7692/abluj?l=en&a=view for details).

Note: Glassfish logging does not capture stack traces.